# Do I need to keep server.key and server.csr for SSL in my rails app directoy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

Currently, in my rails directoy (including my GITHUB) I have these files:

```
website_name.crt
server.csr  
server.key  
server.pass.key
```

Do I have to keep these files here for my SSL to work? Or is it dangerous to keep them there.

Answer (score 0):

You should never ever expose your `server.key` to the public. If you do that basically you have granted them the key to the kingdom! and anybody who has your key can decrypt your SSL/TLS connections and see what's what.

Keep it hidden, keep it safe.